# Query a MySql Database Using The Results of Another Query

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP code is below:

```
    $query1=("SELECT * FROM test_log WHERE '$mktime' < expiry ORDER BY id DESC"); 
        $result1=mysql_query($query1); 
        $num1=mysql_num_rows($result1);


    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        { 
        $id = $row1["id"];
        $keyword = $row1["keyword"];
        $sale = $row1["sale_rent"];
        $agents = $row1["e_num"];
        $email = $row1["email"];
        $cc_email = $row1["cc_email"];
        $expiry = $row1["expiry"];

        $query2= ("SELECT * FROM condo WHERE (location LIKE '%{$row1['keyword']}%' AND sale_rent LIKE '%{$row1['sale_rent']}%' AND e_num LIKE '{$row1['e_num']}') AND (date >= '$sendate') AND TRIM(IFNULL(`phone_1`,'')) <> '' ORDER BY sale_rent, location");
        $result2=mysql_query($query2);    
    $num2=mysql_num_rows($result2);
//the code continues
```

As you can see, I'm using the results of $query1 to query the **condo** table ($query2). I don't want to do this anymore. Could you show me how to combine both queries into a single query & achieve the same result?

Thanks a lot.

**Latest Update** 
Okay this is what I've done so far.

```
<?php   
include("/path/to/my/website.com/public_html/db_connect.php");

$mktime = date('Y-m-d');
$sendate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1 days ago'));

$query1=("SELECT * FROM test_log AS t JOIN condo AS c ON c.location LIKE CONCAT('%', t.keyword, '%') AND c.sale_rent LIKE CONCAT('%', t.sale_rent, '%') AND c.e_num LIKE CONCAT('%', t.e_num, '%') WHERE t.expiry > '$mktime' AND c.date > '$sendate' AND TRIM(IFNULL(c.phone_1, '')) != '' ORDER BY t.id, c.sale_rent, c.location"); 
$result1=mysql_query($query1); 
$num1=mysql_num_rows($result1);

$subject = "Latest Classified Ads - Condo";

$message_tmp  = "<div align='center'>";
$message_tmp .= "<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=100% border=0 id='table1'>";
$message_tmp .= "<TR>";
$message_tmp .= "<TD width=100% height=20 bgcolor='#E5E5E5' align='left' valign='top'>
<p align='center'><b><font size='3'>Comprehensive Real Estate Agency Tools & Property Valuation Services at <a href=\"http://www.cashbillion.com/free-email-alerts\">http://www.cashbillion.com</a></font></b></TD>";
$message_tmp .= "</TR>";
$message_tmp .= "<TR>";
$message_tmp .= "<TD width=100% height=20 bgcolor='#EFEFEF' align='left' valign='top'>
    ~ Classified Ads<br>
    ~ Facebook Promotions<br>
    ~ Public Records Search<br>
    ~ Demographic Statistics<br>
    ~ Property Market Values<br>
    ~ Property Owners Listings<br>
    ~ Real Estate Price Trend Analysis<br>
</p></TD>";
$message_tmp .= "</TR>";
$message_tmp .= "<TR>";
$message_tmp .= "</TR>";
$message_tmp .= "</TABLE>";
$message_tmp .= "</div>";
$message_tmp .= "<h4>List of Latest Classified Ads - Condo</h4>"; 
$message_tmp .= "<table bgcolor='black' cellspacing='1' width='100%'><tr bgcolor='white' align='center'>"; 
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Date</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Location</b></td>"; 
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Property Type</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Tenure</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Status</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Sale / Rent</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Size</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Price</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Price Psf</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Rooms</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Baths</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Renovations</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Furnishings</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Phone</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>Advertiser</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "<td><b>E Number</b></td>";
$message_tmp .= "</tr>"; 
$message_tmp .= "[new_rows]"; 
$message_tmp .= "</table>";
$message_tmp .= "<br>To unsubscribe, go to <a href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/unsubscribe-from-email-alerts/\"><strong>http://www.mywebsite.com/unsubscribe-from-email-alerts/</a></strong>";
$message_tmp .= "<br>Try our free services at <a href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/free-email-alerts/\"><strong>http://www.mywebsite.com/free-email-alerts/</a></strong> your property market information provider.";

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    { 
$new_rows .= "<tr bgcolor='white' align='left'>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["date"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=left><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["location"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["property_type"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["tenure"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=left><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["status"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["sale_rent"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["size"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=left><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["price"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["price_psf"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["rooms"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=left><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["baths"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["renovations"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["furnishings"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "<td align=left><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["phone_1"]."</td>"; 
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["advertiser"]."</td>";  
$new_rows .= "<td align=center><font face=arial size=1.5>".$row1["e_num"]."</td>";
$new_rows .= "</tr>";

    $email = $row1["email"];
    $cc_email = $row1["cc_email"];
    $expiry = $row1["expiry"];
    $keyword = $row1["keyword"];

    if (!empty($new_rows))
            {
            $message = str_replace("[new_rows]",$new_rows,$message_tmp);
            $message .= "<br>Your notification will expire on <font color='#FF0000'><strong>$expiry</strong></font>";
            $message .= "<br>Your requested keyword is <font color='#FF0000'><strong>$keyword</strong></font><br><br>";

    echo $email;
    echo ',';
    echo $cc_email;
    echo ',';
    echo $keyword;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $subject;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $message;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $new_rows;
    echo '<br><br>';

            }
    }

    ?>
```

From this code, what is supposed to happen is a keyword stored in **test_log** is used to query the **location** column of the **condo** table. The results of this query is then emailed to the email address that corresponds with the keyword. The email address is stored in the **email** column of **test_log**.

I've not incorporated the emailing script yet. I'm focusing on displaying the query results first to check whether the right message is supposed to go to the right email or not.

I don't think it is looping properly but I can't explain why either...

**Latest UPDATE**
Okay this is my new query which does not work when run directly on PHP MyAdmin.

```
SELECT condo.location, condo.sale_rent, condo.e_num, condo.date, condo.phone_1 innerQuery.* FROM condo JOIN (SELECT * FROM test_log WHERE '2015-04-15' < expiry ORDER BY id DESC) AS innerQuery WHERE condo.location = innerQuery.keyword AND condo.sale_rent = innerQuery.sale_rent AND condo.e_num = innerQuery.e_num AND condo.date >= '2015-04-14' AND TRIM(IFNULL(`condo.phone_1`,'')) <> '' ORDER BY condo.sale_rent, condo.location
```

The message that I get on PHP MyAdmin is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.* FROM condo JOIN (SELECT * FROM test_log WHERE '2015-04-15' < expiry ORDER BY ' at line 1
```

How do I get this working? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_log AS t
JOIN condo AS c 
ON c.location LIKE CONCAT('%', t.keyword, '%') 
    AND c.sale_rent LIKE CONCAT('%', t.sale_rent, '%')
    AND c.e_num LIKE CONCAT('%', t.e_num, '%')
WHERE t.expiry > '$mktime'
    AND c.date > '$sendate'
    AND TRIM(IFNULL(c.phone_1, '')) != ''
ORDER BY t.id, c.sale_rent, c.location
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar. There is something strange about the way the query is behaving so let me try to explain what it's supposed to do. This is part of a script to handle email alerts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Barmar. The query is behaving strangely so let me explain further. This is part of a script to handle email alerts. The ultimate goal is to use a keyword from test_log to find corresponding matches in the location column of the condo table. If found, send the results to the email address in test_log that corresponds with the keyword in test_log.This is my full code without the email sending part. My 1st goal is to get it to loop properly so that the right message goes to the right recipient via email. At the moment the looping is somewhat messed up. Help me fix the loops.

Comment: Okay this is my first time using this forum so I'm struggling to figure out where to post my new code for you to see. Shall I edit my original question with my new code?

Comment: Yes, edit the question, add an "UPDATE:" section at the end with what you're doing and an explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I won't get into the specifics of the query but I will get you started with what I believe is the first step in the right direction. What you are trying to do should be possible with a nested query:

```
SELECT condo.FieldA, innerQuery.* FROM condo JOIN (SELECT * FROM test_log WHERE '$mktime' < expiry ORDER BY id DESC) AS innerQuery WHERE condo.FieldA = innerQuery.SomeField
```

Comment: Hi, what is FieldA and SomeField? Thanks.

Comment: The purpose of writing fieldA to show you that you will have individually reference each field from the table that you want the query to retrieve.